# SELECT row with meta data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

Table 1

```
===================================
= Id = Name             =  email  =
===================================
= 1  = David            = d@d.com =
===================================
```

Table 2

```
==================================
= uid = key        =  Value      =
==================================
= 1   = Age        =  18         =
= 1   = Tele       =  0123456798 =
==================================
```

The idea is that UID relates to Id to link the tables.

What i would like to do is run one SQL query to get the follow output.

```
=========================================================================
= Id = Name             =  email  = age        =  Tele                  =
=========================================================================
= 1  = David            = d@d.com = 18         = 012345678              =
=========================================================================
```

What is the query I need to run.

Thanks

Comment: Are you going to have only two key values to turn into columns? Or will you have an unknown number?

Comment: Unknown number of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select 
  t.Id,
  t.Name, 
  t.Email,
  (select Value from Table2 t2 where t2.uid = t.Id and t2.Key = 'Age') as Age, 
  (select Value from Table2 t2 where t2.uid = t.Id and t2.Key = 'Tele') as Tele 

from Table1 t
```

The above query works if you know the keys in advance.
It names are unknown get the list of available key names from database:

```
select distinct Key from Table2
```

Comment: Thanks - Stupid question is there anyway of doing that without know what keys are in the table.

Comment: The best I can come up with is to write code that autogenerates the query given the key names.

Comment: OK Thanks.  Everyone has been very helpfull.  I dont understand SQL a great deal.

Comment: In my version of MySQL (5.0) 'Age = ' and 'Tele= ' error out and I have to use ' as Age' and ' as Tele'.

Answer (score 2):

While you have already accepted an answer I am posting this to provide an alternate solution.  You are attempting to `PIVOT` the data and MySQL does not have a pivot function so you will can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement.

If you have a known number of values, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select t1.id,
    t1.name,
    t1.email,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.key='age' THEN t2.value ELSE NULL END) AS age,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.key='tele' THEN t2.value ELSE NULL END) AS tele
FROM Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 
  ON t1.Id = t2.uid
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, t1.email
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28044/1)

But if you have an unknown number of `key` values, then you will want to use a prepared statement o create a dynamic sql version:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when t2.`key` = ''',
      `key`,
      ''' then t2.Value else null end) AS ',
      `key`
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM table2;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.email, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM table1 t1
                  left join table2 t2
                    on t1.id = t2.uid
                  GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, t1.email');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b2ed/5)

Result:

```
| ID |  NAME |   EMAIL | AGE |      TELE |
------------------------------------------
|  1 | David | d@d.com |  18 | 123456798 |
```

Both will produce the same result but the prepared statement version generates the list of `key` values at run-time.

Comment: Nice solution.  I particularly like the statement building inside a query where everything is available.  I was trying to do it with a group_concat() list of key values and a replace which is unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.id,
    t1.name,
    t1.email,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.key='age' THEN t2.value ELSE NULL END) AS age,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.key='tele' THEN t2.value ELSE NULL END) AS tele
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.uid
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, t1.email
```

Comment: You don't need the email in a case statement as it is in table1

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  Id,
  Name,
  email,
  age.Value as age,
  tele.Value as tele
from `Table 1`
left join `Table 2` as age on age.key='Age' and age.uid=Id
left join `Table 2` as tele on tele.key='Tele' and tele.uid=Id
;
```

I simply joined Table 2 several times (as though it was several tables), each time taking only values that match a certain key.  Then for the values I was interested in I just chose the appropriate alias for each and named the column accordingly.

Comment: A bit of explanation about why your solution works would improve this answer.